# Issue with broadcast using Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio, broadcasting

I apologize in advance if the question has been previously answered, but I've searched and found nothing that helps me. As indicated by the question's title, I'm trying to broadcast a package from a server to a set of clients listening for any message.

The client will count the number of messages it receives during one second.

The server side of things goes like this:

```
class Server
{
public:

    Server(boost::asio::io_service& io)
        : socket(io, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 8888))
        , broadcastEndpoint(address_v4::broadcast(), 8888)
        , tickHandler(boost::bind(&Server::Tick, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error))
        , timer(io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(20))
    {
        socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
        socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));

        timer.async_wait(tickHandler);
    }

private:

    void Tick(const boost::system::error_code&)
    {
        socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), broadcastEndpoint);

        timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(20));
        timer.async_wait(tickHandler);
    }

private:

    udp::socket socket;
    udp::endpoint broadcastEndpoint;

    boost::function<void(const boost::system::error_code&)> tickHandler;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;

    boost::array<char, 100> buffer;
```

};

It is initialized and run in the following way:

```
int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        Server server(io);
        io.run();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This (apparently) works fine. Now comes the client...

```
void HandleReceive(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t bytes)
{
    std::cout << "Got " << bytes << " bytes\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <host>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io;

        udp::resolver resolver(io);
        udp::resolver::query query(udp::v4(), argv[1], "1666");

        udp::endpoint serverEndpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
        //std::cout << serverEndpoint.address() << "\n";

        udp::socket socket(io);
        socket.open(udp::v4());

        socket.bind(serverEndpoint);

        udp::endpoint senderEndpoint;
        boost::array<char, 300> buffer;

        auto counter = 0;
        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        while (true)
        {
            socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), senderEndpoint);
            ++counter;

            auto current = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            if (current - start >= std::chrono::seconds(1))
            {
                std::cout << counter << "\n";

                counter = 0;
                start = current;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
```

This works when running both the server and client on the same machine, but doesn't when I run the server on a machine different from that of where I run the client.

First thing is, it seems odd to me that I have to resolve the server's address. Perhaps I don't know how broadcasting really works, but I thought the server would send a message using its socket with the broadcast option turned on, and it would arrive to all the sockets in the same network.

I read you should bind the client's socket to the `address_v4::any()` address. I did, it doesn't work (says something about a socket already using the address/port).

Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm under Windows 8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am a bit surprised this works on the same machine.  I would not have expected the client, listening to port 1666, to receive data being sent to the broadcast address on port 8888.

[`bind()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/bind/overload1.html) assigns a *local* endpoint (composed of a local address and port) to the socket.  When a socket binds to an endpoint, it specifies that the socket will only receive data sent to the bound address and port.  It is often advised to bind to [`address_v4::any()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/any.html), as this will use all available interfaces for listening.  In the case of a system with multiple interfaces (possible multiple NIC cards), binding to a specific interface address will result in the socket only listening to data received from the specified interface<sup>[1]</sup>.  Thus, one might find themselves obtaining an address through [`resolve()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve/overload1.html) when the application wants to bind to a specific network interface and wants to support resolving it by providing the IP directly (127.0.0.1) or a name (localhost).

It is important to note that when binding to a socket, the endpoint is composed of both an address *and* port.  This is the source of my surprise that it works on the same machine.  If the server is writing to broadcast:8888, a socket bound to port 1666 should not receive the datagram.  Nevertheless, here is a visual of the endpoints and networking:

```
                                                               .--------.
                                                              .--------.|
.--------. address: any                         address: any .--------.||
|        | port: any      /                  \    port: 8888 |        |||
| server |-( ----------->| address: broadcast |----------> )-| client ||'
|        |                \    port: 8888    /               |        |'
'--------'                                                   '--------'
```

The server binds to any address and any port, enables the broadcast option, and sends data to the remote endpoint (broadcast:8888).  Clients bound to the any address on port 8888 should receive the data.

A simple example is as follows.

The server:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Server binds to any address and any port.
  ip::udp::socket socket(io_service,
                         ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 0));
  socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));

  // Broadcast will go to port 8888.
  ip::udp::endpoint broadcast_endpoint(ip::address_v4::broadcast(), 8888);

  // Broadcast data.
  boost::array<char, 4> buffer;
  socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), broadcast_endpoint);
}
```

The client:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Client binds to any address on port 8888 (the same port on which
  // broadcast data is sent from server).
  ip::udp::socket socket(io_service, 
                         ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 8888 ));

  ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;

  // Receive data.
  boost::array<char, 4> buffer;
  std::size_t bytes_transferred = 
    socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), sender_endpoint);

  std::cout << "got " << bytes_transferred << " bytes." << std::endl;
}
```

---

When the client is not co-located with the server, then it could be a variety of network related issues:

- Verify connectivity between the server and client.
- Verify firewall exceptions.
- Verify broadcast support/exceptions on the routing device.
- Use a network analyzer tool, such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), to verify that the [time to live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) field in the packets is high enough that it will not be discarded during routing.

---

<sub>1. On Linux, broadcast datagrams received by an *adapter* will not be passed to a socket bound to a specific *interface*, as the datagram's destination is set to the broadcast address.  On the other hand, Windows will pass broadcast datagrams received by an *adapter* to sockets bound to a specific *interface*.</sub>

Comment: Your answer has been quite enlightening, I must admit. My mistake was in opening the server's socket using a given port, instead of port 0.

Comment: Also, I posted the wrong code... these were two versions of the same program, I changed the port number in one of them.

Comment: Why does your code use  ip::udp::v4() instead of ip::address_v4::any()? Do both result in the exact same behavior?